# @Asynchronous and @Scheduled, entityManager or entityManagerFactory?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, jpa, asynchronous, ejb

I'd like to know if using entityManagerFactory in a method annotated with [@Asynchronous](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) or [@schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) is recommanded over the use of an entityManager? From the doc :

> While EntityManagerFactory instances are thread-safe, EntityManager
>   instances are not.

So is it mandatory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stateless and stateful EJBs are specified to be thread-safe, so the EJB container is required to ensure that only one method at a time can be used on a bean instance, so you do not need to worry about EntityManager fields of these bean types.  For singleton, the default concurrency model is container-managed concurrency with write locks, so you don't need to worry about concurrency of EntityManager fields of those beans unless you change the concurrency settings, and then you might need to consider using EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked because asynchronous methods are made on other threads if I'm not mistaking so I thought it wouldn't have been thread safe.

Comment: @Ced Yes, I understood your hesitation and should have explicitly mentioned that the container calls the asynchronous method through the EJB proxy, so for stateless it will allocate a fresh instance from the pool, and for stateful it will block until the EJB is available.